# How to Draw Molecule

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

How do I draw the molecule Coronene, and **place the ticks** around the molecule with the letter H at the end of the ticks, using Tiks?

[image]

here is the code `
\section{Conclusão}
\begin{frame}

```
               \fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\selectfont
               \frametitle{CONCLUSÃO}
               \framesubtitle{}
               \begin{tikzpicture}
               \draw [opacity=0.2](0,-2)grid(4,2);

\draw[red, dashed] (5,0)  circle(0.5cm);
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw,inner sep=0.3535cm] at (5,0) {};    

\draw[red, dashed] (1,0)  circle(0.5cm);
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw,inner sep=0.3535cm,rotate=90] at (1,0) {};

\draw[red, dashed] (2,0)  circle(0.5cm);
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw,inner sep=0.3535cm,rotate=90] at (2,0) {};

\draw[red, dashed] (3,0)  circle(0.5cm);
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw,inner sep=0.3535cm,rotate=90] at (3,0) {};

\draw[red, dashed] (1.5,0.9)  circle(0.5cm);
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw,inner sep=0.3535cm,rotate=90] at (1.5,0.9) {};

\draw[red, dashed] (2.5,0.9)  circle(0.5cm);
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw,inner sep=0.3535cm,rotate=90] at (2.5,0.9) {};
    
\draw[red, dashed] (1.5,-0.9)  circle(0.5cm);
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw,inner sep=0.3535cm,rotate=90] at (1.5,-0.9) {};

\draw[red, dashed] (2.5,-0.9)  circle(0.5cm);
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw,inner sep=0.3535cm,rotate=90] at (2.5,-0.9) {}

                \end{tikzpicture}

                \end{frame}`
```

here is an example of the molecule and one with the ticks on it [image]

Comment: Please edit your post to provide compilable code so people don't have to guess. And never include images of code. That serves no purpose except to annoy people with low bandwidth connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(=*6(-=(-H)-(-H)=*6(-(-H)=(-H)-*6(=(-H)-(-H)=*6(-(-H)=(-H)-*6(
    =(-H)-(-H)=*6(-(-H)=(-H)----)---)---)---)---)--)-=-=-)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

```
\documentclass[border=12mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark} % for background grid
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (O) at (pic cs:cyce);
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\mystep}{\fpeval{(6*sqrt(3)*1.6*1.25)}em} % length of an edge of grid
    \foreach \x in {-2,...,2}{\draw[gray,very thin]
        (O) ++(-\x*\mystep/6,-\mystep/2) -- ++(0,\mystep)
        (O) ++(-\mystep/2,-\x*\mystep/6) -- ++(\mystep,0);}
    \draw[gray,very thin] (O) ++(-\mystep/2,-\mystep/2) rectangle ++(\mystep,\mystep);
\end{tikzpicture}
\chemfig[atom sep=1.6em, atom style={scale=1.25}]{% for scale
    *6(=*6(-=(-H)-(-H)=*6(-(-H)=(-H)-*6(=(-H)-(-H)=*6(-(-H)=(-H)-*6(
    =(-H)-(-H)=*6(-(-H)=(-H)----)---)---)---)---)--)-=-=-)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \tikzmark{cyce}{(cyclecenter1)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that was perfect thanks. but two quick questions 
1) Do you know how do I change the scale of the image ?
2) Do you know how can I draw this image on the xy plane and pile it up forming a box, so I can simulate a grain made of this molecule ? it doesn't need to have many of them, just 3 or 4 of them.

Comment: @conrado10000 see edit